# Update database when datagridview is fill and click on a button

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, datagridview

After some hours of research, I still don't have any idea of how i should code this. I want to update my database when the user fill some specifics columns of my `datagridview` and then he click on the button.

I've seen some binding, some `datatable` and some `dataset`. I've never heard of `databinding` and can't change all my code to respect the `databinding` closure. I've seen some things about `datatable`, but it is the same as `dataset` right? (dataset just being a collection?). And i'm currently using `dataset`, but everything i am testing isn't working.

Here is my code in actual test :

```
public partial class Repair : Form
{
    public Repair()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SqlConnection maConnexion = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database= Seica_Takaya;Integrated Security = SSPI; ");
        maConnexion.Open();
        SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();

        if (Program.UserType == "admin")
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FailOnly";
        }
        else
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FailOnly WHERE ReportingOperator IS NULL";
        }

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        maConnexion.Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();

        Main ff = new Main();
        ff.Show();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection maConnexion = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database= Seica_Takaya;Integrated Security = SSPI; ");
        maConnexion.Open();
        string Var1 = textBox1.Text;
        SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();

        if (Program.UserType == "admin")
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != "")
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BoardName", Var1 + "%");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Machine", Var1 + "%");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNum", Var1 + "%");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FComponent", Var1 + "%");
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FailOnly WHERE BoardName LIKE @BoardName OR Machine LIKE @Machine OR SerialNum LIKE @SerialNum OR FComponent LIKE @FComponent";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != "")
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BoardName", Var1 + "%");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Machine", Var1 + "%");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNum", Var1 + "%");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FComponent", Var1 + "%");
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FailOnly WHERE (BoardName LIKE @BoardName OR Machine LIKE @Machine OR SerialNum LIKE @SerialNum OR FComponent LIKE @FComponent) AND ReportingOperator IS NULL  ";
            }
        }

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        maConnexion.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int var;

        var = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;

        for (i = 0; i < var; i++)
        {
            SqlConnection maConnexion = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database= Seica_Takaya;Integrated Security = SSPI; ");
            maConnexion.Open();
            SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();
            command = new SqlCommand("update FailOnly, FailAndPass set FaultCodeByOp=@Fault, RepairingDate=@RD, RepairingTime = @RT, ReportingOperator=@RO", maConnexion);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fault", dataGridView1.Columns[15]);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RD", dataGridView1.Columns[16]);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RT", dataGridView1.Columns[17]);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RO", dataGridView1.Columns[18]);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            maConnexion.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you !

Edit : Working thanks to Krishna ! A big thank you to him for passing hour with me on my code !

Comment: whatever you wrote in loop is not working ? do you get any error ?

Comment: I have a System.ArgumentException : 'There is no existing link to object type System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn and to another management object' :/

Comment: your update statement is using two tables ? what does this statement mean ? `update FailOnly, FailAndPass`

Comment: Yes because the two tables have the same columns which will be modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping through rows and checking columns, change button click event as below.

change the databinding like below

```
public Repair()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SqlConnection maConnexion = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database= Seica_Takaya;Integrated Security = SSPI; ");
    maConnexion.Open();
    SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();

    if (Program.UserType == "admin")
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FailOnly";
    }
    else
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FailOnly WHERE ReportingOperator IS NULL";
    }

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    DataColumn dcIsDirty = new DataColumn("IsDirty", typeof(bool));
    dcIsDirty.DefaultValue = false;
    dt.Columns.Add(dcIsDirty);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    maConnexion.Close();
    dataGridView1.Columns[19].DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = false;
}
```

Implement CellEndEdit

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1].Value = true;
    }
}
```

now do button click changes

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if(row.Cells[19].Value !== null && (bool)row.Cells[19].Value)//update only changed data
        {
            SqlConnection maConnexion = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database= Seica_Takaya;Integrated Security = SSPI; ");
            maConnexion.Open();
            SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();
            command = new SqlCommand("update FailOnly, FailAndPass set FaultCodeByOp=@Fault, RepairingDate=@RD, RepairingTime = @RT, ReportingOperator=@RO", maConnexion);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fault",row.Cells[15].Value != null ? row.Cells[15].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RD", row.Cells[16].Value != null ? row.Cells[16].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RT", row.Cells[17].Value != null ? row.Cells[17].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RO", row.Cells[18].Value != null ? row.Cells[18].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            maConnexion.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have some errors. First, Cells doesnt exists into row. And second, i still have the exception on "executeNonQuery()" :/

Comment: Told you that query is wrong you cannot update 2 tables in one statement

Comment: Datagridview row will have cells check again

Comment: Actually i can use cell only if i do : datagridview1.Rows[].Cells[];

Comment: Here row is equivalent to Rows[i] so that's not a problem,can you update question with error stack trace ?

Comment: I now can do row.Cell[] because i've declared "DatagridviewRow row1 = new DatagridviewRow()". But when i execute the code, i have an error of index range. It said that the index is outside the range limit. What is an error stack trace ?

Comment: can you show me your error here https://meetings.webex.com/collabs/meetings/join?uuid=M0CWAPNT6PS50CZPVLRYQ8Y5MO-4O2

Comment: Thank you reallyyyyyyyy muccccch mister for giving me some of your time !